# how to select element from array by it value that taken from input user (gets)

Tags: ruby

`enter code here`Good evening everyone
I want to make the user write the start_station from Red_line

### for example in this Scenario

"put ur start Station "
"Park Street"
you will pass these Stations
South Station
,Park Street,
Kendall,
Central.
total number of Stations is :
4.

### the problem is

when i'm trying to make user input the value it doesn't work (like what you can see in *start_station* and **str** input but when I make it Without choosing to work just fine Like What you can't see In *start_station*

I hope it's clear enough, thank you for your time

```
subway =
 {
     "Red_line":["South Station","Park Street","Kendall","Central","Harvard","Porter","Davis","Alewife"]
}

puts"put ur start Station "
 sta = gets.chomp.to_s #<<==== this my attempted to use sta to make it like input  user
puts sta

start_station = subway[:Red_line].index(sta) # <<=== you can see that I put sta as index of subway array
puts start_station

end_station = subway[:Red_line].index("Central")

total_point_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][start_station..end_statio] #name of points
total_number_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][start_station..end_statio].length #number of station

puts "you will pass these Stations"
puts total_point_in_redLine
puts "total number of Stations is "
puts total_number_in_redLine
```

Comment: can you post what are printed in `puts sta`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem...when I run your code and enter `Park Street` when it asks for my station, it tells me I go from `Park Street -> Kendall -> Central` and through 3 stations, which seems correct to me....I'm not sure why you're expecting to pass "South Station" when you start at "Park Street", and your problem statement is unclear to me. Maybe you could try clarifying why you want to pass "South Station" and the problem statement some, might get people to help out some

Comment: in short, I want the user to choose the sart station or point and the end station or point from gets

Comment: thank you for your time it was my fault 
I enter => "Park Street" 
instead of enter =>  Park Street

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# DEFINE SUBWAY
subway =
 {
     "Red_line":["South Station","Park Street","Kendall","Central","Harvard","Porter","Davis","Alewife"]
}

# GET START STATION FROM USER
puts"put ur start Station "
sta = gets.chomp.to_s 
puts sta

# GET START STATION INDEX
start_station = subway[:Red_line].index(sta)

# GET END STATION INDEX
end_statio = subway[:Red_line].index("Central")

# BUG: 
# THIS ONLY WORKS IF END STATION IS AFTER START
# SO ANY STATION AFTER CENTRAL IS A BUG
total_point_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][start_station..end_statio] 
total_number_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][start_station..end_statio].length 

puts "you will pass these Stations"
puts total_point_in_redLine
puts "total number of Stations is "
puts total_number_in_redLine
```

The bug is due to the range `[start_station..end_statio]` being used to access the values in the `subway[:Red_line]` array needs to go from low to high so the first value in the range can not be higher than the last.  When the `start_station` is 5 and the `end_station` is 3 then the range is `subway[:Red_line][5..3]` and you need it to be reversed `subway[:Red_line][3..5]`.

To fix this bug you could use a condition

```
if start_station <= end_statio
  total_point_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][start_station..end_statio] 
  total_number_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][start_station..end_statio].length 
else 
  total_point_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][end_statio..start_station] 
  total_number_in_redLine = subway[:Red_line][end_statio..start_station].length 
end
```